# Compare in Lists in Kotlin?

Tags: list, kotlin, compare

im trying to compare the value "hashtags" in Lists.

The class Person:

```
data class Person(var name: String, var age: Int){
    val hashtags = mutableListOf<String>()
    fun useHashtag(hashtag: String){
        hashtags.add(hashtag) }
}


 fun nextUser(){

       for(item in alleBenutzerListe){

         println(item)

           print("\n")


       }
    }
```

The values:

```
   val vlademir = Person("Vlademir",14)
    val feton = Person("Feton",14)
    val allUserList= listOf(Person(feton.name,14),listOf(Person(vlademir.name,14)))
```

Now in the main function I can use for to see all Persons in "allUserList"

if I add an hashtag for feton it works

```
feton.useHashtag("cooking")
    feton.useHashtag("Football")
vlademir.useHashtag("Football")
vlademir.useHashtag("fortnite")
```

How could I compare the hashtags of these both?

Comment: Like this: 
val compareResultsPerson1 = feton.hashtags + vlademir.hashtags
But with Class person

Answer (score 0):

```
val compareResult = vlademir.hashtags == feton.hashtags
```

Comment: yeah but Im trying this with a function

Comment: and this give me just a boolean.
I want to have the complete list